# R percentage plot after grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

The goal is to obtain male and female answer distribution for books per genre. I am using bellow data frame to illustrate the problem. This is a survey dataset where `X1, X2, X3, X4` are answers given to a question. This data frame reflects after transforming data to reflect answers as dummy variables.

```
book_id, user_id, rate, X1, X2 ,X3 ,X4, Gender,genre
40,1,4.5,0,1,0,0,male,fiction
48,1,3.5,1,0,0,1,male,fiction
54,1,4,1,0,0,0,male,fiction
79,1,2.5,1,0,1,0,male,non-fiction
80,1,4.5,0,0,1,0,male,non-fiction
95,1,5,1,0,1,0,male,non-fiction
95,2,3,0,0,0,1,Female,non-fiction
99,2,4.5,0,0,1,0,Female,non-fiction
2,2,0.5,0,0,0,0,Female,non-fiction
5,2,4.5,1,0,1,0,Female,non-fiction
54,2,4,0,1,0,0,Female,fiction
79,2,2.5,1,0,1,0,Female,non-fiction
80,2,4.5,0,0,1,0,Female,non-fiction
7,2,4.5,1,0,1,0,Female,fiction
7,3,5,1,0,1,0,Female,fiction
9,3,4,0,0,1,0,Female,auto-bio
54,3,4,1,0,0,0,Female,fiction
79,3,2.5,1,0,1,0,Female,non-fiction
80,3,4.5,0,0,1,0,Female,non-fction
17,4,3.5,1,0,0,0,male,auto-bio
21,4,5,1,0,1,0,male,auto-bio
21,5,5,0,1,1,0,male,auto-bio
17,5,0.5,0,0,0,1,male,auto-bio
20,5,5,0,0,1,0,male,fiction
20,6,1.5,0,0,0,1,male,fiction
21,6,5,0,0,1,0,male,auto-bio
21,7,2,1,0,0,0,male,auto-bio
21,8,4.5,1,0,1,0,Female,auto-bio
20,8,4.5,1,0,1,0,Female,fiction
7,8,4.5,1,0,1,0,Female,fiction
22,9,5,0,0,1,0,male,fiction
54,9,4,1,0,0,0,male,fiction
79,9,2.5,1,0,1,0,male,non-fiction
80,10,4.5,1,0,1,0,male,non-fiction
22,10,4.5,0,1,1,0,male,fiction
22,11,0.5,0,0,1,0,Female,fiction
28,11,3.5,1,0,0,0,Female,auto-bio
```

I use `dplyr` to groby by `genre` and `Gender` then `summarize`.

```
df <- books %>% 
  group_by(Gender, genre) %>% 
  summarize(x1 = round(sum(X1)/length(X1)), 
    x2 = round(100 * sum(X1)/length(X2)), 
    x3=round(100 * sum(X1)/length(X3)),
    x4 =round(sum(X4)/length(X4))) %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("Gender", "genre"))
```

My concern is that this doesn't really give a unique number/percentage of books or users per genre per answer. Or does it? Also since I am summing up and getting 1(s) I am not sure its actually reflecting percent users or percent books.

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(genre), value, color = variable, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ Gender)
```

[image]

How do I get a unique number of users and books per genre per answer? Should I be using a conditional approach where inside summarize `select 'book_id' where X1 == 1` then obtain unique Id(s)?

Comment: I don't know what you want. You ask for "a unique number of users and books per genre per answer", which makes it sound like you should be counting users and books, grouping by genre and answer. Instead of counting books, you're averaging answer flags. Each row in your data is a book/user combination, so you are getting neither percent of books nor percent of users, but percent of unique book/user combinations.

Comment: Not knowing if you're getting what you want or not is a good sign that you should be working on a smaller example until you understand. I would suggest subsetting your data to just users 1 and 2 and playing with that data. With such a small input, you'll be able to see and understand what you are generating. If you need help, you'll need to convey your desired output to us much more precisely. With that reduced input you should be able to explicitly write out the output you want.

Comment: Also, as a side note, instead of doing `sum(z) / length(z)`, you can just do `mean(z)` to save yourself some typing.

Comment: @Gregor Since each answer represented by separate column this data frame can't be group by `genre` and `answer`. Or can i? I guess i have to go back to data frame prior to creating dummy variables I guess.

Comment: You're right, you don't have an `answer` column to group by. Maybe you're working around that successfully by taking the means of each separate answer column. That would be equivalent to having long form data with a "answer" and a "response" column, grouping by answer, and taking the mean of response. Or maybe not, it's hard to tell. As I mention above, the biggest confusion is *what result are you looking for?*

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, what i am trying is following: Lets take female facet, and focus auto-bio, the bar should reflect female percent that has given answer X1 for auto-bio books. Make sense?

Comment: Well, good news: that's what you've got.